# How can I "stop" a PHP page from javaScript - meaning mimic the behaviour of closing browser window

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

Very new to PHP and javaScript.

I put up some code that is mining tweets, trough streaming API.

Actually I'm tweaking [this](http://mikepultz.com/2013/06/mining-twitter-api-v1-1-streams-from-php-with-oauth/) code (pasted below) made by Mike Pultz. (thanks!)

It is working fine. It consists in two PHP codes.

-One is the class actually mining. It handles oAuth, open the connection, listen to tweets, and spit them on the page (that last part by now... as a test). It has a `while(1)` infinite loop.

-The other construct an instance of the former, and call the function that starts everything, having oAuth secrets passed as parameters.

So far, I've being calling it (the 2nd script) direct from browser. When I close the window (or hit stop loading button in browser), the connection to twitter is closed (loop stoped). That's good. Though I don't really get why this happens, once the loop is in the other script... I assume the instance is destroyed on page closing, is that so?

Ok so now I'm moving on and starting to write some js to build an interface to all this. I'll have a function calling the php launch script, passing parameters to be searched. I'd like to have a function to stop the stream as well.

The question:
How can I make this happen in PHP? I thought in recreating the miner object and don't call the starter function... But this doesn't fill a very good way of doing so.

calling code:

```
<?php
require 'ctwitter_stream2.php';

$t = new ctwitter_stream2();

$t->login($_cKey,
 $_cSecret, 
 $_aToken,
 $_aSecret);

$t->start(array('query'));
?>
```

mining class (already tweaked from original):

```
<?php

class ctwitter_stream2
{
    private $m_oauth_consumer_key;
    private $m_oauth_consumer_secret;
    private $m_oauth_token;
    private $m_oauth_token_secret;

    private $m_oauth_nonce;
    private $m_oauth_signature;
    private $m_oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    private $m_oauth_timestamp;
    private $m_oauth_version = '1.0';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
        // set a time limit to unlimited
        //
        set_time_limit(0);
    }

    //
    // set the login details
    //
    public function login($_consumer_key, $_consumer_secret, $_token, $_token_secret)
    {
        $this->m_oauth_consumer_key     = $_consumer_key;
        $this->m_oauth_consumer_secret  = $_consumer_secret;
        $this->m_oauth_token            = $_token;
        $this->m_oauth_token_secret     = $_token_secret;

        //
        // generate a nonce; we're just using a random md5() hash here.
        //
        $this->m_oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());

        return true;
    }

    //
    // process a tweet object from the stream
    //
    private function process_tweet( $_data)
    {
        print_r($_data);

        return true;
    }

    //
    // the main stream manager
    //
    public function start(array $_keywords)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            $fp = fsockopen("ssl://stream.twitter.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if (!$fp)
            {
                echo "ERROR: Twitter Stream Error: failed to open socket";
            } else
            {
                //
                // build the data and store it so we can get a length
                //
                $data = 'track=' . rawurlencode(implode($_keywords, ','));

                //
                // store the current timestamp
                //
                $this->m_oauth_timestamp = time();

                //
                // generate the base string based on all the data
                //
                $base_string = 'POST&' . 
                    rawurlencode('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json') . '&' .
                    rawurlencode('oauth_consumer_key=' . $this->m_oauth_consumer_key . '&' .
                        'oauth_nonce=' . $this->m_oauth_nonce . '&' .
                        'oauth_signature_method=' . $this->m_oauth_signature_method . '&' . 
                        'oauth_timestamp=' . $this->m_oauth_timestamp . '&' .
                        'oauth_token=' . $this->m_oauth_token . '&' .
                        'oauth_version=' . $this->m_oauth_version . '&' .
                        $data);

                //
                // generate the secret key to use to hash
                //
                $secret = rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_consumer_secret) . '&' . 
                    rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_token_secret);

                //
                // generate the signature using HMAC-SHA1
                //
                // hash_hmac() requires PHP >= 5.1.2 or PECL hash >= 1.1
                //
                $raw_hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $secret, true);

                //
                // base64 then urlencode the raw hash
                //
                $this->m_oauth_signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode($raw_hash));

                //
                // build the OAuth Authorization header
                //
                $oauth = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' . $this->m_oauth_consumer_key . '", ' .
                        'oauth_nonce="' . $this->m_oauth_nonce . '", ' .
                        'oauth_signature="' . $this->m_oauth_signature . '", ' .
                        'oauth_signature_method="' . $this->m_oauth_signature_method . '", ' .
                        'oauth_timestamp="' . $this->m_oauth_timestamp . '", ' .
                        'oauth_token="' . $this->m_oauth_token . '", ' .
                        'oauth_version="' . $this->m_oauth_version . '"';

                //
                // build the request
                //
                $request  = "POST /1.1/statuses/filter.json HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                $request .= "Host: stream.twitter.com\r\n";
                $request .= "Authorization: " . $oauth . "\r\n";
                $request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";
                $request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
                $request .= $data;

                //
                // write the request
                //
                fwrite($fp, $request);

                //
                // set it to non-blocking
                //
                stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

                while(!feof($fp))
                {
                    $read   = array($fp);
                    $write  = null;
                    $except = null;

                    //
                    // select, waiting up to 10 minutes for a tweet; if we don't get one, then
                    // then reconnect, because it's possible something went wrong.
                    //
                    $res = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 600, 0);
                    if ( ($res == false) || ($res == 0) )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    //
                    // read the JSON object from the socket
                    //
                    $json = fgets($fp);

                    //
                    // look for a HTTP response code
                    //
                    if (strncmp($json, 'HTTP/1.1', 8) == 0)
                    {
                        $json = trim($json);
                        if ($json != 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
                        {
                            echo 'ERROR: ' . $json . "\n";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    //
                    // if there is some data, then process it
                    //
                    if ( ($json !== false) && (strlen($json) > 0) )
                    {
                        //
                        // decode the socket to a PHP array
                        //

                            //
                            // process it
                            //
                            $this->process_tweet($json);


                    }
                }
            }

            fclose($fp); 
            sleep(10);

        }

        return;
    }
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to stop the php code from Javascript, i would like to propose a solution for you.

Lets assume that you have started the script, and some time later you wish to stop the script

1) You can ping a php page via AJAX and pass a parameter that will save the setting to the file.

2) In the php code that is doing the stream mining, in the while you can the existence of a value in the file

Assuming the AJAX ping successfully saved the value, the while loop will intercept it and perform a break that will exit the loop successfully, thereby stopping it

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. That seems a very good idea. I'll try that for sure. Meanwhile I was still searching the web, and came across a suggestion to assign the var pointing to the mining object to `null`.  Would that do the trick? Or will the while(1) loop will prevent the object to be garbage collected? (Are there a garbage collector right?). Thanks.